# My Venus flytrap’s mouths won’t shut

Tags: carnivorous-plants, venus-fly-trap

How come my Venus flytrap’s mouths are sort of turned out and won’t shut? I have tried touching the trigger hairs, and I always keep the soil moist. Please help.

Comment: Need some more info, are these traps old? Did they do the job already? These traps can only be used a few times, after that they won't work anymore.

Comment: ^ and pictures please

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Venus' flytraps' leaves will turn convex when they don't get enough sunlight during the day. They need as much sun as is physically possible. Keeping them outside from sunrise to sunset is best, but they can do well in 6+ hours of direct sunlight. If you haven't kept it outside before, it won't be acclimated to that amount of sunlight and will burn the leaves if you put it outside all day all at once. Put your plant outside for an hour or two, and then each consecutive day add an hour or two until it's outside all day. This will allow the plant to build up a tolerance to the UV rays of the sun. I hope this helps!